# How to declare and add multiple exogenous variables in SARIMAX model?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a similar question posted two years ago on this topic. Unfortunately for a newbie like me is too short to understand. I am new in Python and I'm still learning how to declare data and how to work with time series. Can you please help me to declare:

endog= what steps I should follow? ... df.iloc or another easier solution?
exog=I wknow I have also to add a constant... df.iloc or another easier solution?

While there are some helpful examples online, the only referral to multiple exogenous variable such as:
"First of all you have to define your exogenous input as an array-type structure with dimensions nobsxk where nobs is the number of your endogenous observations (i.e. supposing that you have a time series, the length of your time series) and k the number of your additional exogenous variables. Supposing that you use a ndarray for this purpose you may begin with something like

exog = np.empty([nobs, k])

and then fill it with the values of your exogenous variables."

I don't really understand  how to fill the values of multiple variables.

I am using Python 3.7.4, imported a *.csv document where on the first column there is datetime monthly data, second column is the endogenous variable y, and then followed by columns x1, x2, x3, x4 exogenous variables. I would like to run a SARIMAX model with endog exog varibles and use multiple exogenous factors.
Many thanks for your help and patience.